# Is there any penalty for losing your UAV in Multiplayer Rush?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

I love using the UAV in Bad Company 2 multiplayer Rush mode, it's great for taking out tanks or entrenched positions.  Sometimes, I get a little risky and it gets shot down pretty quickly.  I figure that it doesn't really hurt my team as long as I'm using it, because I'm not really dying and we don't lose a ticket.

Is there any penalty to losing a UAV in Rush mode other than having to wait for UAV respawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No particular penalty. You just lose the bonus it represents. It's really useful for spotting enemies and mark them so your teammates have intel information on the field. It's also useful as you say to attack tanks and soldiers with the mounted MG.
I usually succeed in keeping it alive the time my friends blow up up to 4 MCOM stations. The only drawback is that when it explodes, you have to run during a few minutes to join back the action which is now far away from your position :)